# single_term_title() running before get_the_title()

Tags: terms, blog, get-the-title

This is a strange "problem" but I've had this happen on a few installs and I was wondering if anybody could give an explanation on why / how this happens.

On a blog category if I code:

`<?php echo get_the_title(1).': '.single_term_title(); ?>`

Outputted to my screen: `UncategorizedBlog:`

On the otherhand, if I do this:

`<?php echo get_the_title(1); ?>: <?php single_term_title(); ?>`

I get the correct output `Blog: Uncategorized`.

I'm not sure if this is a PHP problem or a WordPress or maybe it's something in my code I've messed up along the way. Anyway I was curious as to why it appears that way since I would think order of operations would print the first function first, move onto the concatenation, then proceed to the `single_term_title()` but apparently this is not the case.

Comment: Please correct your question. `<?php echo get_the_title(1).': '.single_term-title(); ?>` should be `<?php echo get_the_title(1).': '.single_term_title(); ?>`

Comment: This is a very common mistake among WordPress >coders< ... And yes the "WHY IS THIS HAPPENING AT ALL" is a PHP issue, **HOWEVER** "WHY IS THE FUNCTION OUTPUTTING WRONGLY" is actually an ON-topic question regarding WordPress Codex - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_term_title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<?php echo get_the_title(1).': '.single_term_title('', false); ?>`

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_term_title) the second argument of single_term_title determines whether to "Display the title (TRUE), or return the title to be used in PHP (FALSE).
Default: TRUE"

Comment: Ok, so that's A solution but that doesn't really explain Why `single_term_title()` shows up first when it's listed second.

Comment: When using echo and the . operator, all strings are concatenated first before being echoed. When you call the single_term_title() function, there is an echo that is called within that function, and nothing is returned. You need to include that second FALSE parameter so that a string is returned instead of echoed. This might explain it better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109322/concatenating-echo-syntax-in-php#answer-8109326